# Undoing an old fast foreward commit

Tags: git, git-merge, undo, fast-forward

Looking back at some work I did, there was a fast forward commit that really makes it hard to tell what was worked on, so I would like to move that commit to it's own branch. Here is my current situation:

```
A--B--C--D
```

And lets say that C is the one commit I want to move. C also (from the FF commit) has it's own branch that is on it (`branch2`). I want it to look like:

```
A--B--------C2--D
    \      / 
     \    /
      C--/
```

So C is on `branch2` and C2 is a merge commit and A, B, and D are all on `master`.

Here is some extra info:

```
$ git reflog show branch2
245c52c branch2@{0}: commit: C
7c2a064 branch2@{1}: branch: Created from HEAD

$ git reflog show master
c0a8aff master@{0}: commit: D
244c52c master@{1}: merge branch2: Fast-forward
8a93b2f master@{2}: commit: B
fe872d8 master@{3}: commit: A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```
 A--B--C--D (master)
       |
   (branch2)
```

You can reset `master` and redo the [merge (in a non-FF way)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), then [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) `D` (or [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), if D is actually multiple commits)

```
git checkout master
git branch tmp # mark D if you need to
git reset --hard B
git merge --no-ff branch2

 A--B----C2
     \   /
      --C (branch2)
         \
          --D (tmp)
```

Then:

```
git cherry-pick D
```

If D was actually composed of multiple commits, the '`tmp`' branch would come in handy:

```
git rebase --onto master branch2 tmp
```

That would replay all commits after branch2 (so excluding C), up until `tmp` HEAD (that is `D`) on top of `master` (`C2`)

Comment: Is there a way of soing this without touching D? There are quite a few commits after D in reality.

Comment: @thesecretmaster that is what the rebase --onto comes in: there can be any number of commits of D on master: they will all been replayed on top of master.